# Can't set regexp check with is text end by

Tags: regex

Text

```
hello regexp
Furshet Toilet Soap Lily of the valley 100g
La Fabelo privet hair color cream tone 100ml
La Fabelo Bio hair color cream tone400ml
La Fabelo privet hair color cream tone 300ml
La Fabelo privet 100ml hair color cream tone
La Fabelo privet 100g hair color cream tone
```

I need to filter lines that end with ' 100g' or  ' 100ml'

The result must be 2 line:

```
Furshet Toilet Soap Lily of the valley 100g
 La Fabelo privet hair color cream tone 100ml
```

Here regexp:

' 100[g|ml]$'

But it not help

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/SqUMIn/1, the main issue is that you confused a character class with a grouping construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `\s100(g|ml)$`.

`100[g|ml]$` will check space followed by `100` followed by either `g`, `|`, `m` or `l` (character class)

[snippet](https://regex101.com/r/zmxuGP/1)

Comment: Not help. This \s100(g|ml)$    not work

Comment: Well, to me, [it does](https://regex101.com/r/zmxuGP/1/)